# Getting minumum value but greater than 0

Tags: java, string

I have day, seconds, hours. I want to get the `minimum` value but not `zero` among these there variables. How can I get that ? I can get the minimum value, if these variables are Integers.

```
    long time = 1387670712 * (long) 1000;
    Date past = new Date(time);
    Date now = new Date();

    String day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago";
    String sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + "minutes ago";
    String hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago";
```

Comment: sort and get the smallest one!

Comment: or just compare them....get the smallest one!

Comment: value + "String". How can I sort them ?

Comment: convert them into a sortable type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need something like next:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long time = 1387670712 * (long) 1000;
    Date past = new Date(time);
    Date now = new Date();

    long i1 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
    long i2 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
    long i3 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
    String day = i1+" days ago";
    String sec = i2+" minutes ago";
    String hours = i3 +" hours ago";
    long[] values = new long[] {i1,i2,i3};
    Arrays.sort(values);
    for(int i = 0 ;i<values.length;i++){
        if(values[i] != 0){
            String postfix = values[i] == i1 ? day : (values[i] == i2 ?  sec : hours);
            System.out.println("minimum = " + postfix );
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("no values or all 0");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please describe this line String postfix = values[i] == i1 ? day : (values[i] == i2 ?  sec : hours);

Comment: That's ternary operator(alternative for if-then-else).